# Select COUNT of column and GROUP BY

Tags: php, mysql, select, group-by

Here I am with a problem I can't solve myself.

My problem is:

I need to SELECT the count of a column, but I also need to GROUP BY on that same column. What I've tried so far is not returning as I expected.

Here is what I tried:

```
'SELECT COUNT(user_id) AS total_donors
    FROM ' . DONATION_SECURITY_TABLE .
    " WHERE payment_status = 'Completed' 
    GROUP BY user_id"
```

This is how my table looks like:

```
id    user_id    payment_status
1     20         Completed
2     33         Completed
3     44         Completed
4     20         Pending
5     33         Pending
6     44         Completed
7     20         Completed
```

As you see, a single user_id can be Pending or Completed more than once, but I want my query to return **3** (based on the table example above).

So, I want my query to COUNT GROUPED user_ids if payment status is completed.

Ideas?

Comment: You count rows, not columns. Count of columns is known.

Comment: Can you please paste the expected output you are looking for?

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com: When the argument of `COUNT` is a column, I think it's quite reasonable to say that you're "counting the column", meaning that you're counting the rows where that column is non-null. (The OP didn't write "count of **columns**", (s)he wrote "count of **a column**".)

Comment: @ruakh: Nope, you are counting **rows** matching your `WHERE` criteria. Column holds no data. Rows do.

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com: You're counting rows that (1) match your `WHERE` clauses and (2) have a non-null value for the argument you specify to `COUNT`. In the case of (say) `COUNT(column_name)`, it's reasonable to say that you're "counting `column_name`". That's how English works. If you don't like it, you can go learn Lojban instead.

Comment: @ruakh: You have one column, so tell me what you want to really count here? It's not how English works. It's how your English works I think. If you got crayons in the cup what would you count to find out how many are red? Cup or crayons? EOT.

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com: If it's a physical cup, I count "crayons in the cup". If it's an instance of a class named `Cup` that affords a method named `count` to obtained the number of `Crayon` instances it owns, then yes, I count the cup!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `DISTINCT` keyword to select the unique User ID's like so

```
"SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS total_donors
FROM " . DONATION_SECURITY_TABLE .
" WHERE payment_status = 'Completed'
```

Answer (score 2):

sounds like a distinct count is what you need. throw away the group by and try this:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS total_donors
FROM
  mytable
WHERE
  payment_status = 'Completed'
```

Answer (score 2):

For a result of 3, replace your `Count(user_id)` with `Count(distinct user_id)` and remove the group by.

That gives you the count of unique user_ids with a payment status of completed.

Answer (score 1):

since you are only interested on the count of `user_ID`, you don't need to use `GROUP BY` clause

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_ID)
FROM tableName
WHERE payment_status = 'completed'
```

when you try to add `GROUP BY` clause. the result is very different from what you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `user_id`) as `Total` FROM `Donation_Table`
WHERE `payment_status` = 'Completed'
```